# JFrame's keylistener with actionlistener

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener, keylistener

I'm trying to add a KeyListener to my JFrame and the key pressed will do all the code inside an ActionListener class.

Example :

When I press F1, it will trigger the ActionListener class. Doing all the instructions.

Any help?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have a KeyListener "call" an ActionListener. Rather create a separate method with all the instructions and have both the KeyListener and the ActionListener call this same method.

Also in this situation, don't use a KeyListener which behaves capriciously when keyboard focus can change, and instead favor use of [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Answer (score 1):

> the key pressed will do all the code inside an ActionListener class.

Instead of using an `ActionListener` you can use an `Action`. An `Action` is basically the same as an ActionListner, but you can define extra properties which make it easier to use with the keyboard. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more information and working examples. As a side note Swing components are designed to use Actions.

Once you create the `Action` you have different options:

1. You can add the `Action` to a `JMenuItem` and if you defined the "accelerator" key then the `Action` will be invoked automatically when the F1 key is pressed.
2. If you don't use a `JMenuItem` then you need to bind the `KeyStroke` to the `Action` manually. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make and Remove Key Bindings] for the basics of manually adding a binding.(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html#howto).